# how to increment or decrement textfield value using uistepper?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uistepper

I currently have a *UITextField* which has some value in it and also i have a *UIStepper* besides it.
I want to know how to use the *UIStepper* so as increment/decrement the textfield value.

**CODE**:

the value changed action of the **UIStepper**

1st I tried this

```
- (IBAction)changedX:(UIStepper*)sender 
{
double value = [sender value];
self.XStepper.value=[self.XCoordinate.text doubleValue];
self.XCoordinate.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g",value];
NSLog(@"%f",value);
}
```

**then i changed it to this:**

```
if ([sender value]==1) {

   double temp= [self.XCoordinate.text doubleValue];
    temp=temp+1;
       self.XCoordinate.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g",temp];

}

else
{
    double temp= [self.XCoordinate.text doubleValue];
    temp=temp-1;
    self.XCoordinate.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g",temp];

}
```

i am not understanding how do i take the current *UITextField* value and update it in *UIStepper* so that current value should be incremented/decremented accordingly.

Thanks

Comment: I have given a similar [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16391738/767730). The difference being value could be changed by both stepper and a slider, here it is a textfield and stepper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the stepper.value to the default value in viewDidAppear/viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad;
    {

        [self.stepper setValue:10];
      // steppr get valye from textfiled

    }

  - (IBAction)stepperChanged:(UIStepper *)sender
    {

             NSUInteger value = sender.value;
             NSLog(@"%d",value);
             NSLog(@"%@",self.XCoordinate.text);

            self.XCoordinate.text = [@(value) stringValue];

            [self.stepper setValue:value];

    }
 -(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
{

 [self.stepper setValue: self.XCoordinate.text.doubleValue];

}
```

hope it help You

Comment: i used your code,but it starts from 0 and goes on incrementing from there onwards.

Comment: To form a string from a number, it would be more graceful if you use literals. `[@(value) stringValue]`.

Comment: @kirtimali the textfield changes to 1 and increments from there,i had already tried this,it doesnt take the current value,it starts from 1 and increments from there,i want to take the value from the textfield and update that value using stepper.

Comment: @kirtimali e.g i already have a value 212 in my UITextField,now i when i use the increment/decrement the stepper it has to change to 211 or 210,depending on whether i incremented or decremented.It shouldnt start from 0 and increment to 1.

Comment: you set viewdidload or textfieldendediting 
[self.stepper setValue:yoyrtxt double value];

Comment: @vin issue soleved or not ?

Answer (score 0):

You should not do it in this method. From what I understand, you want to be able to change the text in the `UITextfield` from the `UIStepper` and also, if the text in the `UITextfield` changes, you want to update the Stepper.

You should use the `Value Changed` event of the `UIStepper` to update the text field, but when you want to update the actual stepper from the text field, you should have another method.

```
- (void)updateStepper:(UIStepper *)stepper fromTextField:(UITextField *)textfield {
    NSInteger value = [textfield.text integerValue];
    [stepper setValue:value];
}
```

Comment: so are you saying to call the above method from the UIStepper's value changed method?

Comment: no. you should call this method when the value is changed from the textfield. For example, if you type in new value from the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

This alternative worked for me. Every time I edit the textfield the stepper.value is set. This way when I tap the stepper it has works with the value it already has, the textfield value or it's own value.

```
- (IBAction)didTapStepper:(UIStepper *)sender {
    self.textFieldName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)sender.value];
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    if(textField == self.textFieldName){
        self.stepperName.value = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", self.textFieldName.text, string] doubleValue];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

**EDIT:** Don't forget to add the Delegate **UITextFieldDelegate**,
and assign yourself to it.

```
self.textFieldName.delegate = self;
```